# How to add increment values using a hashmap of <Integer,HashMap<Integer,Integer>

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hashmap

I have a table known as client in which there i a column know as created_time , so actually i want to plot a map that in such a way that i can tell in which which year and which month how many clients are added ?  and now the ask is suppose in Nov 2018 2 clients were added and in December 2018 0 clients are added so in December also i will show 2 (its like the above months + the current month) and if in January 2019 1 client is added so i will show 3 and so on

SO to solve this problem i have created a hashMap in which the first key is year and i have made another hashMap in which the key is month and then the no of client which is added e.g. HashMap>

Expected Output ::

```
clientsByMonth": {
                    "2018": {
                        "10": 1,(1 client added in oct)
11,1( as 0 client added in nov)
12,2( as 1 client added in december)
                    },
                    "2019": {
                        "1": 2,   ( as no client added )
                        "2": 4,   (as 2 client added)
                        "3": 5,
                        "4": 5
                    }
```

```
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> clientsByYear = new HashMap<>();
    List<Client> clientList = clientRepository.findAll();

    for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {

        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(clientList.get(i).getCreatedTime().getTime());
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        Integer month = localDateTime.toLocalDate().getMonth().getValue();
        Integer year = localDateTime.toLocalDate().getYear();

        if (!clientsByYear.containsKey(year)) {
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> clientByMonth = new HashMap<>();
            clientByMonth.put(month, 1);
            clientsByYear.put(year, clientByMonth);
        } else {
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> clientByMonth = clientsByYear.get(year);
            if (!clientByMonth.containsKey(month)) {
                int clients = 0;
                for (int j = month - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if (clientByMonth.containsKey(j)) {
                        clients = clients + clientByMonth.get(j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                clientByMonth.put(month, (clients + 1));
            } else if (clientByMonth.containsKey(month)) {
                int clients = clientByMonth.get(month);
                clientByMonth.put(month, (clients + 1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Vatsal - what problem are you facing with your program? Are you getting any error.

Comment: No i am not getting any error , its just that its not summing up properly and i am getting incorrect output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below, it should solve your problem if I understood your problem correctly

1. Iterate all clients
2. Add  if year map doesn't contain it
3. Else get the existing entry from yearmap
4. Add month map with iteration counter as latest value

```
for (int i = 1; i <=clientList.size() ; i++) {
        ...

     if (!clientsByYear.containsKey(year)) {
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> clientByMonth = new HashMap<>();
            clientByMonth.put(month, i);
            clientsByYear.put(year, clientByMonth);
        } else {
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> clientByMonth = clientsByYear.get(year);
            clientByMonth.put(month, i);
        }
      }
    System.out.println(clientsByYear);
  }
```

Expected : Input data is sorted based on time asc

Comment: thanks for the effort but i have to add the no of clients on a monthly basis and thats where i am stuck , so this gives me an correct output that for october month in 2018 2 clients but if in nov month there is no new client added i need to show the last month value and if added then  no of client lastmonth +  new client this month

Comment: Oh, I get it now. So client count from aug will be base for client count of Nov. And is that only in that year? I mean is a value from Dec 2018, passed on to Jan 2019? Correct? If true, is data list sorted by time?

Comment: yes and yes the value will also get passed in to Jan 2019 and it will keep on adding like it did in 2018

Comment: Trying to write pseudo without testing. Please pardon me for that. Check the answer, assuming data is sorted by month/year before entering into for loop

Comment: thanks for the effort and yes the list will come in order only with 2018 and their months in order and then 2019 and their months

Comment: Is it working Ok? I used for loop counter this time to put client count. I see a gap for month where there is no data available for a month, I am sure it can be fixed by a key comparison in map of months, or by running a fixed 1-12 loop. Let me know if it sounds fine to you.

Comment: yes its working , thanks and yes it sounds good to me but according to which one should be better, i only need to display a one year data so suppose as its nov 2019 , i only need to display from dec 2018 to nov 2019

Comment: I tried like the way of comparing each month and adding and its working fine , the only part left is that i want only last 12 months data but now i am getting more than that , its too long here to write how i attempted

Comment: Instead of fetching all the data from repository `clientRepository.findAll()`, why don't you find the records for last 12 months only?

Comment: Yes ,it's resolved. The java util time was deprecated so instead of that I used Calendar, it worked like a charm, thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to know it worked. But I am curious to know, java.time library was introduced in Java 8 to cover up the shortcomings of Calendar API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/datetime/index.html). When you say java time is deprecated, which version of Java you are using?

Comment: i am using java 1.8